# jquery ui tabs with ajax content: content not rendered

Tags: jquery-ui-tabs

Is it possible to have the content for a jquery-ui tab-pane be another html document?

```
         <div id='tabs' class="ui-tabs">

             <ul>

    <li><a href="Text.html" ><span>Text</span>/a></li>
    <li><a href="Notes.html" ><span>Notes</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="Glossary.html" >Glossary</span></a></li>

              </ul>

        </div>
```

I think my page is set up as in the documentation here:     http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#Ajax_mode

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

   $("#tabs").tabs();



});
```

but my pages do not display. In the debugger I see that the external document has indeed been loaded (and there is a loading... message in the tab briefly) but the content is not being *rendered*. Is there additional javascripting required to get the external pages to be rendered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: updated working code. Previous had some typo's.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    var tabContainers = $('div#bodyTabs div');
    tabContainers.hide().filter(':first').show();
    $('div#tabs ul a').click(function ()
    {
        if(this.hash == '#tab2')
        {
                // do something different for tab2
            }else
            {
            tabContainers.hide();
            tabContainers.filter(this.hash).show();
            $('div#tabs ul li').removeClass('selected');
            $(this).parent().addClass('selected');
            }                                                           
            return false;
    });
}).filter(':first').click();
window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
</script>
</body>
<html>
<div id='tabs' class="ui-tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tab1" ><span>Text</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2" ><span>Notes</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab3" ><span>Glossary</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="bodyTabs">
    <div id="tab1" style="display:none;">
        <iframe src="Text.html"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div id="tab2" style="display:none;">
        <iframe src="Notes.html"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div id="tab3" style="display:none;">
        <iframe src="Glossary.html"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

For new html document you need to load them in an iframe. You can even use if's and change the source of just one frame (but this way you can see changes in previous frame is you switch tabs)

EDIT:

Added code on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RJBeC/)

Comment: thank you for the helpful code examples. I have a simpler approach working that doesn't use iframes (the documents to be loaded are not really bona-fide HTML documents, just snippets of HTML -- I removed everything outside the BODY tags and the body tags). But I will use your iframe approach with fully-fledged HTML documents.

Answer (score 0):

It seems ok, except from a markup error in the second and third li element: you close a span tag which was not opened...

```
     <div id='tabs' class="ui-tabs">
         <ul>
          <li><a href="Text.html" ><span>Text</span>/a></li>
          <li><a href="Notes.html" >Notes**</span>**</a></li>
          <li><a href="Glossary.html" >Glossary**</span>**</a></li>
         </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: thanks. I've corrected the typo (here on SO -- was ok on the website). I've tracked the rendering problem down to a class that I had neglected to remove from the content I wanted to display, namely ui-tabs-hide.  I had originally been displaying the content all as one large document and had been using the class to make only the desired div visible.